# jquery mouseenter mouseleave not functioning correctly in ios

Tags: jquery, ios, mobile-safari, mouseenter, mouseleave

What I've noticed is that when using jquery's `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event attached to multiple `divs` (via a class) on mobile when you tap on the element I see that `mouseenter` fires as it's suppose to and when I tap outside of the element `mouseleave` fires, but in ios (safari) the `mouseleave` does not fire unless i tap another element in the group (which actually fires twice, once for the `mouseleave`of the event, and again for the `mouseenter` on the new element).

Also, if the events are attached to only one element then the `mouseleave` event doesn't fire at all.

Does anyone have a solution to this issue? I've searched quite a bit for this, but the little that i did find was never solved.

view demo in ios device/xcode simulator: http://jsfiddle.net/76yqv3tc/7/